# estimatedAssetCount returns a wrong count

Tags: ios, swift, count, photokit, phassetcollection

I need to display the camera roll album with the count of images in it. I'm using the below code to get the camera roll album.

```
let smartCollections = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(.SmartAlbum, subtype: .SmartAlbumUserLibrary, options: nil)
smartCollections.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock { object, index, stop in
    if let collection = object as? PHAssetCollection {
        print(collection.estimatedAssetCount)
    }
}
```

I have only 28 images in the camera roll in the Photos app. But the `estimatedAssetCount` property returns the value 9223372036854775807!

This only happens for OS created albums like the camera roll. For user created regular albums, the correct value is returned. Am I doing anything wrong or is this a bug?

If it is, is there any other way to get the correct image count?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Should have looked a little longer. Going in to the header file of `PHAssetCollection` reveals this little piece of info.

> These counts are just estimates; the actual count of objects returned
>   from a fetch should be used if you care about accuracy. Returns
>   NSNotFound if a count cannot be quickly returned.

So I guess this is expected behavior and not a bug. So I added this below extension method to get the correct image count and it works.

```
extension PHAssetCollection {
    var photosCount: Int {
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType == %d", PHAssetMediaType.Image.rawValue)
        let result = PHAsset.fetchAssetsInAssetCollection(self, options: fetchOptions)
        return result.count
    }
}
```

Comment: Working perfect!

Answer (score 5):

`9223372036854775807` is the value of `NSNotFound` on some systems. The documentation for `PHAssetCollection` mentions that it could return `NSNotFound` when the count cannot be returned.

If you want to only resort to fetching when necessary, you should check for `NSNotFound`:

```
let smartCollections = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(.SmartAlbum, subtype: .SmartAlbumUserLibrary, options: nil)
smartCollections.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock { object, index, stop in
    guard let collection = object as? PHAssetCollection else { return }

    var assetCount = collection.estimatedAssetCount
    if assetCount == NSNotFound {
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType == %d", PHAssetMediaType.Image.rawValue)
        assetCount = PHAsset.fetchAssetsInAssetCollection(collection, options: fetchOptions).count
    }

    print(assetCount)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Isuru's answer slightly modified for Swift 5

```
extension PHAssetCollection {
    var photosCount: Int {
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType == %d", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)
        let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: self, options: fetchOptions)
        return result.count
    }

    var videoCount: Int {
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType == %d", PHAssetMediaType.video.rawValue)
        let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: self, options: fetchOptions)
        return result.count
    }
}
```